# Having problems installing.packag("BatchGetSymbols")

Tags: r, quantmod

I can't install.package("BatchGetSymbols") for some reason.
I am just doing this:

```
install.packages('BatchGetSymbols')
library(BatchGetSymbols)
```

and i am getting this:

```
> install.packages('BatchGetSymbols')
Installing package into ‘/home/rstudio/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.6’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
Warning in install.packages :
  dependency ‘XML’ is not available
trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/BatchGetSymbols_2.5.7.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 181321 bytes (177 KB)
==================================================
downloaded 177 KB

ERROR: dependency ‘XML’ is not available for package ‘BatchGetSymbols’
* removing ‘/home/rstudio/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.6/BatchGetSymbols’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘BatchGetSymbols’ had non-zero exit status

The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘/tmp/RtmpAhaAos/downloaded_packages’
> library(BatchGetSymbols)
Error in library(BatchGetSymbols) : 
  there is no package called ‘BatchGetSymbols’
```

Does anyone understand why there is a problem??

Comment: It seems i need >= R 4.0.0

Answer (score 1):

Install the latest version of R before

Commands to install: https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/

Choose the version of your system and run the commands

After that try to install the library.